# Update single package from Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn when running Trusty Tahr

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm tasked to update a package on a Ubuntu Server Trusty Tahr installation. Specifically rfc5766-turn-server which is really old on Trusty.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rfc5766-turn-server

As you see the latest package for Trusty is 3.2.3.1-1 while for Utopic Unicorn a newer 3.2.4.1-1 exists.

Is it possible to just update this single package using apt? This is a dedicated turn-server so downloading the source and all the build tools is not something I want to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply download the `.deb` and install it with `dpkg -i file.deb`. However, this will be a one-time install and you will not get updates for this package as part of the normal `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` process. If you want to get them, you will have to add the Utopic repositories to your `sources.list` and use `/etc/apt/preferences` to indicate that they should be used only for this package, with something like

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=trusty
Pin-Priority: 501

Package: rfc5766-turn-server
Pin: release n=utopic
Pin-Priority: 502
```

See `man apt_preferences` for details about how this works, but basically: Apt always installs the package with the highest priority; version numbers are only used as tie-breakers when several packages have the highest priority (then the one with the highest version number is installed). By default, all packages have priority 500, so if you have both the Trusty and the Utopic repositories in your `sources.list`, the Utopic versions will be installed since they have higher version numbers. We start by assigning priority 501 to all Trusty packages, so they will not be upgraded to Utopic since they have higher priority. Then we assign priority 502 to the package `rfc5766-turn-server` from Utopic so that it will be preferred over the Trusty version (we could also assign priority 501 to it of course...).